# Mysql Query with Multiple Joins to Excel in Symfony Admin

Tags: mysql, excel, symfony1, doctrine

I have created a nice registration frontend app for registering new users for an Event.

I'm now looking to create a Excel export of all attendees from the admin generated backend.

At the moment I've wrote a bit of SQL that give me the exact table I need:

```
select 
CONCAT(p.first_name,' ',p.last_name) as "Registered User",
p.email_address as "Register Email",
p.country as "Register Country",
t.name as "Attendee Type" ,
CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ',a.last_name) as "Attendee",
CONCAT(disc.name, ' ',disc.sex) as "Discipline",
CONCAT(divi.category, ' ', divi.weight) as "Division",
a.sex as "Sex",
a.club_name as "Club Name",
a.accomodation as "Accommodation",
a.`sharing_with1` as "Sharing With A",
a.`sharing_with2` as "Sharing With B",
a.`flight_number` as "Flight Number",
a.`flight_datetime` as "Flight Date",
a.`flight_time` as "Flight Time",
if(a.visa > 0, 'Yes', 'No') as "Visa",
a.dob as "Date of Birth",
a.passport as "Passport",
a.`expiry_date` as "Passport Expiry"

from `profile` p, `type` t,

`attendee` AS a LEFT JOIN `division` AS divi ON (a.division_id = `divi`.id) 
LEFT JOIN discipline AS disc ON (divi.discipline_id = disc.id)

where a.profile_id = p.id
 AND a.type_id = t.id
```

As you can see there are few standard and outer joins.

I also realize I can in a template create the ordiary HTML table with the data and change the file headers to define it as an Excel File... User downloads and opens the file in Excel and never knows the difference.

What I want to know is; based on what I have e.g. the sql and the output plan what is the best way to make best use of symfony to do this?

Note: Symfony 1.4 with Doctrine.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: You should change the joins to explicit: `FROM attendee AS a JOIN profile AS p ON a.profile_id = p.id JOIN \`type\` AS t ON a.type_id = t.id LEFT JOIN ...`

Comment: I could but does it make any difference. Can the way I have cause any problems. I always do standard joins with the where tableA.tableB_id = table_b.id. This at the moment is giving the correct output.

Comment: No, both ways are equivalent in this case. As you already know, you can't write an outer join with `WHERE`. Using `JOIN` for inner joins too is better because you separate the join logic from the conditions (you may have or add later, you have none in this example). Also, you can't write `a LEFT JOIN (b JOIN c)` with `WHERE`.

Comment: That is a very fair point. I did a bit of research since last comment I see its just better practice to do it the way you suggest. Thanks. I will from now on do it the right way. It would read better that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think CSV is also a nice option, csv file can be opened with Excel.

Anyway, what you can do is create a new action on your module. I suggest you to add it to the [actions params](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/06-Admin-Generator#chapter_06_sub_actions) (It will be displayed with the "new record" button).

In your action, you just have to execute your request:

```
$this->dbh = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getConnection('doctrine');
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetchAll();
```

You can add the response headers you need like this:

```
$this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/poney/excel');
```

If you want you can bypass the templating:

```
return $this->renderText($html);
```

Usefull if you try to serv CSV \o/